# Is there a way to 'complete current statement' and 'exit current method'?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ IDEA, I can do *'Complete current statement'* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will complete my current statement and put the caret on generated a new line. Is there a shortcut (or a way to configure) to tell IntelliJ that the current statement (in a method) is the last one and I want to exit out of the current method?

For example, my caret is currently after `assertNotNull(a)` and I want to start writing my `assertB()` method. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> will not get me out of the `assertA()` method I always have to manually remove the extra line and get my caret out of the method with the Down Arrow.

```
@Test
public void testX() {
    assertA();
    assertB();
}

private void assertA() {
    assertNotNull(a)|
}
```

Comment: I was never thinking that this functionality is so necessary.

Comment: I thought that many of IntelliJ functionality wasn't actually necessary... That is until I became addicted to it.

Comment: As of IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 there is no such shortcut. You can try to record a macro that will consist of pressing Ctrl-Shift-Enter and then Down.